# How to offset a character in PHP?

Tags: php, char

I'm trying to implement rot13 cipher algorithm in PHP. But it is a little difficult in comparison with Java:

```
char a = 'A';
a += 13;
System.out.println(a);

output will be : N
```

However, in php 5.0:

```
   $a = 'A';
   $a += 13;
   echo "$a";

  output will be: 13.
```

How could I implement it just as same as Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like the increment/decrement operators will do what you're looking for, see example 1 here http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.increment.php

Comment: do **not** use 'rot13' and 'cipher' in one sentence please.

Answer (score 1):

As php is loosely typed, when you add 13 to your string, your string will evaluate to 0.

What you could do is:

```
$a = "A";
$val_a = ord($a);
$val_a += 13;
echo chr($val_a);
```

Comment: using `str_rot13()` would be more efficient: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php if you need rot13.

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com If that is exactly what you need, yes, but this is more general and answers the question in the title.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to specifically do rot13, you can just use the [`str_rot13()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-rot13.php) function.

```
$a = 'A';
echo str_rot13($a); // Outputs N
```